# How can I change css for every DOM object in the page in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have a things inspector and this things inspector has two titles. I wan to be able to change the css on this titles and make their font size a bit smaller( default fontSize is 16px and I want to drop it to 12px). I tried to get these titles class and use this method to change their size:

```
var element = document
                    .getElementsByClassName("sapUiUx3TVTitleSecond")[1];
            element.style.fontSize = '12px';
var element = document
                    .getElementsByClassName("sapUiUx3TVTitleFirst")[1];
            element.style.fontSize = '12px';
```

it does work and I can see the change but as soon as the page finishes loading ( page loading takes couple of second because it needs to read a json object) title sizes go back to its default. 
I dont even know this is a right way to access DOM elements and change their CSS.

Please point me to the right direction of how to change DOM object css in SAPUI5 in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new CSS file which you include in your index.html.

Just add the needed selectors with the modified attributes in this custom CSS:

```
.sapUiUx3TVTitleSecond, .sapUiUx3TVTitleFirst {
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

Edit: if you need to change it programmatically, you could use the addStyleClass("yourStyle") method which is available to every UI element

Comment: The way you describe does work, I still want to programmatically change the css and be able to apply it only to the part of my app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Qualiture but addStyleClass() doesnt work in my case because I want to change the CSS of the title of Things inspector which is not a control by itself. addStyleClass() only works with sapui5 control.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the script after dom gets completely loaded. Try like this

```
$("document").ready(function()
{

  var element = document
                .getElementsByClassName("sapUiUx3TVTitleSecond")[1];
        element.style.fontSize = '12px';
      var element = document
                .getElementsByClassName("sapUiUx3TVTitleFirst")[1];
        element.style.fontSize = '12px';   
})
```

Comment: I just tried this and still it gets overwritten at the end. I dont know why is that But I can see that it gets changed first and then go back to its default.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
       $(".sapUiUx3TVTitleSecond").css("font-size","12px");   
})
```